# Does PublishTransactionsFilter exist on Tridion versions before 2011?

Tags: tridion

I am trying to use Alex Klock's solution with regards to querying the publishingqueue to see if in item is already still in it. His post about it is here: http://www.codedweapon.com/2012/03/tridion-publishengine/

I am using Tridion 2009 SP1, but it seems I don't have **PublishTransactionsFilter** available in my code abse. In the top of my file I did include: `using Tridion.Contentmanager.Publishing;`

Any exmaple on how to get something similar to work in Tridion 2009? Especially the `PublishEngine.GetPublishTransactions` method. I can't find a similar method in the 2009 API. Only methods which need a specific TCMUri or XML.

Comment: I think I solved the question already by taking a closer look at the API guides... Unfortunately it's only a Tridion 2011 feature :'(

Comment: Keep in mind you can query the publishing queue on Tridion 2009 SP1, it just requires the use of a different API. Depending on where you want to inspect the publishing queue, you should use the TOM or the TOM.NET.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Frank, I have added the question for how it works in 2009 API. I seem to get stuck on the PublishTransaction method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the ManagementInfo Class which is documented in the 'Templating and Customization Manual TOM 2009 SP1.chm' help file that comes SDL Tridion 2009.

To quote:

> The ManagementInfo object supports the following methods:
>
> *GetListPublishQueue* Gets a list of items in the publishing queue(s) or
>   scheduler.  GetListPublishTransactions Gets a list of publish
>   transactions
>
> *GetListPublishQueue*: 
>   Summary - Gets a list of items in the publishing
>   queue(s) or scheduler.

These classes and methods are contained in the COM version of the TOM DLL so you will need to use Interop to access this from Microsoft.NET

Comment: Thanks Chris! I will look into this way of getting into the queue items. I will watch the performance closely on this one though...

Answer (score 4):

Yes you found it yourself but indeed just to confirm, the `GetPublishTransactions` method *is specific to SDL Tridion 2011.*

The code on the link you provided is using the 2011 API of looking into the queue.

Comment: Do you by any chance know if it possible to do something like this in 2009? I have tried to play around using GetManagementInfo (from the Forum) but this seems to be an old TDSE method...

Comment: Only possible via COM or Business Connector. The TOM.NET before 2011 did not implement any of the ManagementInfo classes